# Why do my rspec Rails tests on ONE model is taking 10 minutes ?! (Rails 3.2/rspec 2/Guard/spork)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec

I have rspec tests defined in my app but they are taking ages!
In my whole app, I have 438 tests running in 37 minutes. That's only 10 tests per minute.

I use Guard for rspec, Spork so I think it should be much faster. there must be something wrong going on.

For example, the rspec test on the model 'Prize' is taking 13 minutes for 134 tests. It is terribly slow! Here is my spec for Prize:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Prize do
  let(:admin_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }

  before(:each) do
    @attr = {
      prize_name: "lorem ipsum",
      prize_short_description_for_modals: "yokoko gygy gygy",
      prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account:  "longer better longer better longer better",
      prize_detailed_webpage_url: "http://www.example.com",
      prize_image_url: "http://www.example2.com",
      prize_image_alt:"French",
      prize_type: "Jackpot prize",
      prize_initial_stock_quantity: 100,
      prize_remaining_stock_quantity: 5,
      prize_unit_certified_market_value:  450,
      prize_date_for_certified_market_value: 2.days.from_now,
      prize_displayed_value_on_website: 456,
      prize_require_additional_user_info: true,
      prize_max_nb_days_for_claiming: 24,
      prize_expiry_date: 75.days.from_now,
      prize_category: "computer",
      prize_sourcer_company_name: "Nefertiti",
      prize_sourcer_contact_point_name: "Gentle Man",
      prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone: "01 45 67 68 77",
      prize_sourcer_contact_point_email: "gentle.man@example.com",
      prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details: "From 9 TO 5pm, Mon. to Fri.",
      prize_sourcer_crm_profile_url: "http://www.example3com",
      prize_fully_stocked_validated:  true,
      # admin_user_id: 1,
      # as: :admin_user
    }
  end

    it { should respond_to(:prize_name) }
    it { should respond_to(:prize_short_description_for_modals) }
    it { should respond_to(:prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account) }
    it { should respond_to(:prize_detailed_webpage_url) }
    it { should respond_to(:prize_image_url) }
    it { should respond_to(:prize_image_alt) }
    it { should respond_to(:prize_type) }
    it { should respond_to(:prize_initial_stock_quantity) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_remaining_stock_quantity) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_unit_certified_market_value) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_date_for_certified_market_value) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_displayed_value_on_website) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_require_additional_user_info) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_max_nb_days_for_claiming) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_expiry_date) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_category) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_sourcer_company_name) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_name) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_email) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_sourcer_crm_profile_url) }
  it { should respond_to(:prize_fully_stocked_validated) }

    it { should respond_to(:admin_user_id) }
    it { should respond_to(:deal_id) }
    # its(:admin_user) { should == admin_user }

    # it { should be_valid }

  # it "should create a new instance given a valid attribute" do
  #   prize.create!(@attr)
  # end

  # -- Active Records Tests --------------------------------------------------------
  describe "tests on prize's active record" do
    it { should belong_to(:admin_user).with_foreign_key('admin_user_id')  }
    it { should belong_to(:deal) }
  end

  # Tests on Mass-Assginement
    describe "tests on prize's attributes mass assignement" do
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_name) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_short_description_for_modals) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_detailed_webpage_url) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_image_url) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_image_alt) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_type) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_initial_stock_quantity) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_remaining_stock_quantity) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_unit_certified_market_value) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_date_for_certified_market_value) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_displayed_value_on_website) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_require_additional_user_info) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_max_nb_days_for_claiming) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_expiry_date) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_category) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_sourcer_company_name) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_name) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_email) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_sourcer_crm_profile_url) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:prize_fully_stocked_validated) }

      it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:admin_user_id) }
      it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:deal_id) }

      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:admin_user_id).as(:admin_user) }
      it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:deal_id).as(:admin_user) }
    end

  # -- Controller Tests --------------------------------------------------------
  describe "tests on prize's controllers" do
  end

  # -- Models Tests --------------------------------------------------------
  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_name" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_name) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_name) }

    it "should reject prize with names that are too long" do
      long = "a" * 101
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_name => long)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_name)
    end

    it "should reject prize with names that are too short" do
      short = "a" * 4
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_name => short)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_name)
    end
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_short_description_for_modals" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_short_description_for_modals) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_short_description_for_modals) }

    it "should reject attribute that are too long" do
      long = "a" * 301
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_short_description_for_modals => long)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_short_description_for_modals)
    end

    it "should reject attribute that are too short" do
      short = "a" * 9
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_short_description_for_modals => short)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_short_description_for_modals)
    end
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account) }

    it "should reject attribute that are too long" do
      long = "a" * 10001
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account => long)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account)
    end

    it "should reject attribute that are too short" do
      short = "a" * 9
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account => short)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_long_description_for_rules_and_user_account)
    end
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_detailed_webpage_url" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_detailed_webpage_url) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_detailed_webpage_url) }
    it { should_not allow_value("string but not url").for(:prize_detailed_webpage_url) }   
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_image_url" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_image_url) }
    it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:prize_image_url).case_insensitive }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_image_url) }
    it { should_not allow_value("stringbutnoturl").for(:prize_image_url) }     
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_image_alt" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_image_alt) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_image_alt) }

    it "should reject attribute that are too long" do
      long = "a" * 31
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_image_alt => long)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_image_alt)
    end
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_type" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_type) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_type) }
    it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:prize_type).in_array(PRIZE_TYPES) }
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_initial_stock_quantity" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_initial_stock_quantity) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_initial_stock_quantity) }

    it { should validate_numericality_of(:prize_initial_stock_quantity).only_integer }
    it { should validate_numericality_of(:prize_initial_stock_quantity).is_greater_than_or_equal_to(1) }
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_unit_certified_market_value" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_unit_certified_market_value) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_unit_certified_market_value) }

    it { should validate_numericality_of(:prize_unit_certified_market_value).only_integer }
    it { should validate_numericality_of(:prize_unit_certified_market_value).is_greater_than_or_equal_to(1) }
    it { should validate_numericality_of(:prize_unit_certified_market_value).is_less_than_or_equal_to(1000000) }
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_date_for_certified_market_value" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_date_for_certified_market_value) }
    it { should_not allow_value(Time.zone.today - 1).for(:prize_date_for_certified_market_value).on(:create) } # has to be at least today
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_require_additional_user_info" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_require_additional_user_info) }
    it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:prize_require_additional_user_info).in_array(%w(true false)) }
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_max_nb_days_for_claiming" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_max_nb_days_for_claiming) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_max_nb_days_for_claiming) }

    it { should validate_numericality_of(:prize_max_nb_days_for_claiming).only_integer }
    it { should validate_numericality_of(:prize_max_nb_days_for_claiming).is_greater_than_or_equal_to(7) }
    it { should validate_numericality_of(:prize_max_nb_days_for_claiming).is_less_than_or_equal_to(90) }
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_expiry_date" do
    it { should_not allow_value(Time.zone.today - 1).for(:prize_expiry_date).on(:create) } # has to be at least today
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_category" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_category) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_category) }
    it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:prize_category).in_array(PRIZE_CATEGORIES) }
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_sourcer_company_name" do

    it "should reject attribute that are too long" do
      long = "a" * 101
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_sourcer_company_name => long)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_sourcer_company_name)
    end

    it "should reject attribute that are too short" do
      short = "a" * 2
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_sourcer_company_name => short)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_sourcer_company_name)
    end
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_sourcer_contact_point_name" do

    it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_name) }
    it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_name)}

    it "should reject attribute that are too long" do
      long = "a" * 101
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_name => long)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_name)
    end

    it "should reject attribute that are too short" do
      short = "a" * 2
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_name => short)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_name)
    end
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone" do

    context "if prize_sourcer_contact_point_name present" do # test when sourcer is present
      before { subject.stub(:prize_sourcer_company_name?) { true } }
      it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone) }
      it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone) }
    end 

    context "if prize_sourcer_contact_point_name not present" do # test when sourcer is not present
      before { subject.stub(:prize_sourcer_company_name?) { false } }
      it { should_not validate_presence_of(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone) }
    end 

    it "should reject attribute that are too long" do
      long = "a" * 21
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone => long)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone)
    end

    it "should reject attribute that are too short" do
      short = "a" * 3
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone => short)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_direct_phone)
    end
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_sourcer_contact_point_email" do

    context "if prize_sourcer_contact_point_name present" do # test when sourcer is present
      before { subject.stub(:prize_sourcer_company_name?) { true } }
      it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_email) }
      it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_email) }
      it { should_not allow_value("blah").for(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_email) } # need to include format with @
    end 

    context "if prize_sourcer_contact_point_name not present" do # test when sourcer is not present
      before { subject.stub(:prize_sourcer_company_name?) { false } }
      it { should_not validate_presence_of(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_email)  }
    end 

    it "should reject attribute that are too long" do
      long = "a@" * 51
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_email => long)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_sourcer_contact_point_email)
    end

  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details" do

    context "if prize_sourcer_contact_point_name present" do # test when sourcer is present
      before { subject.stub(:prize_sourcer_company_name?) { true } }
      it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details) }
      it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details) }
    end 

    context "if prize_sourcer_contact_point_name not present" do # test when sourcer is not present
      before { subject.stub(:prize_sourcer_company_name?) { false } }
      it { should_not validate_presence_of(:prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details)  }
    end 

    it "should reject attribute that are too long" do
      long = "a" * 501
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details => long)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details)
    end

    it "should reject attribute that are too short" do
      short = "a" * 3
      hash = @attr.merge(:prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details => short)
      Prize.new(hash).should have(1).error_on(:prize_sourcer_how_to_contact_details)
    end
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_sourcer_crm_profile_url" do

    context "if sourcer present" do # test when sourcer is present
      before { subject.stub(:prize_sourcer_company_name?) { true } }
      it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_sourcer_crm_profile_url) }
      it { should_not allow_value(" ").for(:prize_sourcer_crm_profile_url) }
      it { should_not allow_value("stringbuturl").for(:prize_sourcer_crm_profile_url) }
    end 

    context "if sourcer not present" do # test when sourcer is not present
      before { subject.stub(:prize_sourcer_company_name?) { false } }
      it { should_not validate_presence_of(:prize_sourcer_crm_profile_url) }
    end 
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for prize_fully_stocked_validated" do
    # it { should validate_presence_of(:prize_fully_stocked_validated) }
    # it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:prize_fully_stocked_validated).in_array(%w(true false)) }
  end

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for admin_user_id" do
     it { should validate_presence_of(:admin_user_id) }
     it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:admin_user_id) }
     it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:admin_user_id).as(:admin_user) }
     it { should validate_numericality_of(:admin_user_id) }
  end  

  describe "tests on prize's models validations for deal_id" do
     it { should validate_presence_of(:deal_id) }
     it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:deal_id) }
     it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:deal_id).as(:admin_user) }
     it { should validate_numericality_of(:deal_id) }
  end 

end
```

I have adjusted Garbage collector(http://makandracards.com/makandra/950-speed-up-rspec-by-deferring-garbage-collection) but it almost had no effect.

```
class DeferredGarbageCollection

  DEFERRED_GC_THRESHOLD = (ENV['DEFER_GC'] || 10.0).to_f

  @@last_gc_run = Time.now

  def self.start
    GC.disable if DEFERRED_GC_THRESHOLD > 0
  end

  def self.reconsider
    if DEFERRED_GC_THRESHOLD > 0 && Time.now - @@last_gc_run >= DEFERRED_GC_THRESHOLD
      GC.enable
      GC.start
      GC.disable
      @@last_gc_run = Time.now
    end
  end
end
```

I use https://github.com/tmm1/perftools.rb to assess the time spent and understand why it takes so long. Here is the analysis by perftools

```
Total: 533 samples
      45   8.4%   8.4%       45   8.4% garbage_collector
      38   7.1%  15.6%       40   7.5% String#gsub
      35   6.6%  22.1%       35   6.6% String#=~
      20   3.8%  25.9%       20   3.8% Hash#initialize_copy
      15   2.8%  28.7%       29   5.4% Enumerable#inject
      14   2.6%  31.3%      201  37.7% I18n::Backend::Base#translate
      13   2.4%  33.8%      203  38.1% Kernel#catch
      13   2.4%  36.2%       18   3.4% URI::Parser#make_regexp
      12   2.3%  38.5%       12   2.3% PG::Connection#async_exec
      10   1.9%  40.3%      483  90.6% Array#map
       9   1.7%  42.0%       18   3.4% ActiveRecord::DynamicMatchers#respond_to?
       9   1.7%  43.7%        9   1.7% Hash#has_key?
       9   1.7%  45.4%        9   1.7% String#gsub!
       7   1.3%  46.7%        7   1.3% Class#logger
       7   1.3%  48.0%        7   1.3% Regexp#match
       6   1.1%  49.2%       12   2.3% #<Module:0x00000002cbf5a0>#normalize_key
       6   1.1%  50.3%       64  12.0% ActiveModel::Translation#human_attribute_name
       6   1.1%  51.4%        6   1.1% Kernel#is_a?
       6   1.1%  52.5%        7   1.3% Kernel.Float
       6   1.1%  53.7%        6   1.1% Regexp#===
       5   0.9%  54.6%      209  39.2% #<Module:0x00000002cbf5a0>#translate
       5   0.9%  55.5%      282  52.9% ActiveModel::Errors#generate_message
       5   0.9%  56.5%        5   0.9% Array#concat
       5   0.9%  57.4%       47   8.8% Hash#each
       5   0.9%  58.3%        5   0.9% I18n::Config#backend
       5   0.9%  59.3%       18   3.4% Kernel#dup
       5   0.9%  60.2%       10   1.9% MonitorMixin#mon_synchronize
       4   0.8%  61.0%        6   1.1% #<Module:0x00000002cbf5a0>#config
       4   0.8%  61.7%       24   4.5% #<Module:0x00000002cbf5a0>#normalize_keys
       4   0.8%  62.5%        4   0.8% ActiveRecord::Translation#lookup_ancestors
       4   0.8%  63.2%        4   0.8% Hash#delete
       4   0.8%  64.0%        6   1.1% Hash#except!
       4   0.8%  64.7%        4   0.8% Hash#values_at
       4   0.8%  65.5%       51   9.6% I18n::Backend::Simple::Implementation#lookup
       4   0.8%  66.2%        4   0.8% Kernel#require
       4   0.8%  67.0%        4   0.8% Kernel#respond_to?
       4   0.8%  67.7%        4   0.8% String#intern
       3   0.6%  68.3%        3   0.6% #<Module:0x00000002cbf5a0>#normalized_key_cache
       3   0.6%  68.9%        6   1.1% #<Module:0x007f8a0cd5fdc0>#__temp__
       3   0.6%  69.4%       10   1.9% ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#extract_pg_identifier_from_name
       3   0.6%  70.0%       42   7.9% ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber#call
       3   0.6%  70.5%        3   0.6% Array#-
       3   0.6%  71.1%        9   1.7% Hash#merge
       3   0.6%  71.7%      123  23.1% I18n::Backend::Base#default
       3   0.6%  72.2%        8   1.5% I18n::MissingTranslation::Base#initialize
       3   0.6%  72.8%        3   0.6% IO#write
       3   0.6%  73.4%        3   0.6% Kernel#throw
       3   0.6%  73.9%      480  90.1% RSpec::Core::Example#run
       3   0.6%  74.5%        3   0.6% Regexp#initialize
       3   0.6%  75.0%        3   0.6% String#%
       3   0.6%  75.6%        7   1.3% Time#minus_with_coercion
       2   0.4%  76.0%       22   4.1% ActiveModel::Validations::UrlValidator#validate_each
       2   0.4%  76.4%       20   3.8% ActiveRecord::LogSubscriber#sql
       2   0.4%  76.7%        3   0.6% ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber#color
       2   0.4%  77.1%        2   0.4% ActiveSupport::Notifications::Fanout#listeners_for
       2   0.4%  77.5%        4   0.8% Arel::Visitors::Visitor#visit
       2   0.4%  77.9%       10   1.9% Array#collect
       2   0.4%  78.2%        2   0.4% Array#flatten!
       2   0.4%  78.6%        2   0.4% Array#hash
       2   0.4%  79.0%        2   0.4% Class#configurations
       2   0.4%  79.4%        7   1.3% Class#match
       2   0.4%  79.7%       17   3.2% Hash#except
       2   0.4%  80.1%        2   0.4% Logger::SimpleFormatter#call
       2   0.4%  80.5%        2   0.4% Marshal.dump_without_mocks
       2   0.4%  80.9%       63  11.8% Module#interpolate
       2   0.4%  81.2%      361  67.7% Prize#_run__2501234485523728663__validate__1858047214644115366__callbacks
       2   0.4%  81.6%        2   0.4% Symbol#to_s
       2   0.4%  82.0%        2   0.4% Thread#[]
       2   0.4%  82.4%        2   0.4% Time#initialize
       1   0.2%  82.6%        2   0.4% #<Module:0x00000002cbf5a0>#handle_exception
       1   0.2%  82.7%        1   0.2% ActiveModel::Errors#[]
       1   0.2%  82.9%      280  52.5% ActiveModel::Errors#add
       1   0.2%  83.1%      278  52.2% ActiveModel::Errors#normalize_message
       1   0.2%  83.3%       67  12.6% ActiveModel::Name#human
       1   0.2%  83.5%      364  68.3% ActiveModel::Validations::Callbacks#run_validations!
       1   0.2%  83.7%        8   1.5% ActiveModel::Validations::NumericalityValidator#parse_raw_value_as_a_number
       1   0.2%  83.9%      149  28.0% ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator#validate
       1   0.2%  84.1%        4   0.8% ActiveRecord::Associations::JoinDependency#initialize
       1   0.2%  84.2%        5   0.9% ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods#respond_to?
       1   0.2%  84.4%        1   0.2% ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::BeforeTypeCast#read_attribute_before_type_cast
       1   0.2%  84.6%        4   0.8% ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Dirty#write_attribute
       1   0.2%  84.8%        1   0.2% ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Write#type_cast_attribute_for_write
       1   0.2%  85.0%       62  11.6% ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter#log
       1   0.2%  85.2%       69  12.9% ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#disable_referential_integrity
       1   0.2%  85.4%        1   0.2% ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#quote
       1   0.2%  85.6%        1   0.2% ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLColumn#type_cast_with_extended_types
       1   0.2%  85.7%        1   0.2% ActiveRecord::ExplainSubscriber#call
       1   0.2%  85.9%        1   0.2% ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#where
       1   0.2%  86.1%        1   0.2% ActiveRecord::Result#hash_rows
       1   0.2%  86.3%        1   0.2% ActiveRecord::Scoping::ClassMethods#current_scope=
       1   0.2%  86.5%        5   0.9% ActiveRecord::SpawnMethods#except
       1   0.2%  86.7%       30   5.6%
```

The whole file is here if necessary: https://docs.google.com/document/d/16F38guxjBVFpu8Xp1rwK14TWREPcM3wtiLvfBGG7NB0/edit?usp=sharing

I read a few articles on how to improve time, but I would like first to understand why it is so slow (30 minutes!) and then I could pick the right test optimization techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's using most of the time generating the error messages for your validations. You could try to optimize that, but if what you're looking for is a simple speedup, you can just stub that whole part of the process. I would just stub `ActiveModel::Errors#generate_message` with `"error message"`, which should save a lot of processing time.

```
ActiveModel::Errors.any_instance.stub(:generate_message).and_return('error message')
```

Comment: @Alex_Siri thanks, in which file would you put that? in spec_helper.rb ?

Comment: I would put that in a before block inside of your spec file, so it only applies there